# Pointer in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I have code:

```
char* s="abc";
```

I have a question, what's datatype of a variable in this code?

1. datatype of `s` is `int`
2. s is `string`?

So, if datatype of `s` is `int`, why `cout<<s` is "abc"?

Comment: Nothing in your example has the type of `int`. And you do not have a `std::string` anywhere, you have a `char*` and a `const char[]` literal

Comment: The data type is a pointer. I would read up on them.

Comment: @AnT You are correct, edited.

Comment: Datatypes can be basic or derived. Pointers are a derived datatype. So in this case s is neither string or int, it is of type pointer.

Answer (score 3):

The type of `s` is what the variable is declared to be, nothing else. It is pointer to `char`, or `char*`. It points to the first element of a read-only `char` array, which is why it should really be `const char*`. In fact, the conversion to `char*` is deprecated in C++.

Answer (score 1):

The data type is `char *` (character pointer). It internally contains an integer (the size depends on the processor architecture that you are targeting). It shows up as "ABC" because the `<<` operator is overloaded to display character pointers as strings. If you want to see the integer value, cast it to `void *`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's ratiocinate.
If `s` had type `int` when its declaration would contain type specifier `int` or some typedef name (a user defined alias for `int`) that equivalent to `int`. For example

```
int s;
```

or

```
typedef int MyPersonalType;
MyPersonalType s;
```

The same way if `s` had type `std::string` it would be declared like

```
std::string s;
```

Neither the first nor the second is used in the declaration of `s`.
`s` is declared like

```
char* s;
```

So it has type `char *` that is it is a pointer to character. Moreover `s` is initialized by a string literal

```
char* s="abc";
```

In this case `s` is initialized by the address of the first character of the string literal.

So when you use statement

```
std::cout << s;
```

this string literal is outputed.

Take into acccount that this record

```
char* s="abc";
```

is valid in C. In C++ you have to specify also qualifier const

```
const char* s="abc";
```

because string literals are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

"abc" is a literal consisting of the three characters a, b, and c followed by a null terminator.

It can be assigned to a const char*. You can also assign it to a char* but that is dangerous since you cannot modify the contents of the literal.

cout contains an overload that will track along the input pointer until it reaches the null terminator; outputting the characters as it goes.

So, s is modelling a sting of characters.